# How To Restore a deleted Google maps marker

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-maps

> this is the html code which loads all of the files needed to make the program work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <title>Accessibilita</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&amp;key=AIzaSyD3Xz7-z7U_XzZiaOlx9khhtFSld8vd0k4"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="js/marker_json.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
     <header class="header">
  <ul id="c0">
      <li><img class="img1" src="img/BorghiArtistici.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img class="img2" src="img/logo2municipio.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img class="img3" src="img/RegioneLazio.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
  </header>
  <div id="map-canvas" class="my-map"></div>
  <div id="panel">
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="" placeholder="inserisci parametri di ricerca...">
    <input type="button" value="Cerca" onclick="searchAddress()">
    <input type="button" value="Cancella" onclick="removeAddress()">
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> this is the css code which causes the map to be displayed

```css
html, body,
      #map-canvas {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
   
    .my-map {
     height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
     position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 6.5%;
  border: outset;
      }
   
      #panel {
            position: absolute;
   top: 25%;
   left: 16%;
   margin-left: -180px;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: #FFF;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 50%;
      }
   
   #address{
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 70%;
   }
    
 .img1 {
   width: 10%;
   height: 20%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0%;
   top: 0%;
 }
 .img2 {
    width: 20%;  
       height: 20%;
    top: 0%;
       left: 30%;
       position: absolute;
 }
 .img3 {
     width: 20%;  
        height: 20%;
     position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 60%;
 }
 .header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 
 /*float menu */
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
   }

   li {
    float: left;
   }
   
   #C0
    {
 z-index: -1;
  
   }
```

> this is the javascript file which makes the asyncronous loading of the json file which is parsed inside the code and recalled inside a function to make the marker and infowindow objects visible. Within this file I create and delete markers using onclick event which fires whenever "cerca" button and "cancella" button are clicked

```js
var map;
var arr = [];
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.897097, 12.513234)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "json/marker_json.json";
var arr; 

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

 var infowindow = [];
    var marker = [];
 function searchAddress(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            (function(i){ //new line 
            infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                title: arr[i].title,
    content: arr[i].content
            });
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    title: arr[i].title,
     icon: arr[i].icon,
     size: arr[i].size,
     coords: arr[i].coords,
     type: arr[i].type,
     draggable: false,
     //map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,                        
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].latitude,arr[i].longitude)
                });
      marker[i].setMap(map) 
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
                    infowindow[i].open(map,this);
            });
            })(i); //new line
    }
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
    marker[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function removeAddress(){
 setAllMap(null);
 arr = [];
}
```

> this is the json file which contains the needed information to display inside the map

```html
[
{
"title": "Coop.Sociale Prassi e Ricerca Onlus", 
"latitude": 41.897115,
"longitude": 12.513300,
"content": "Cooperativa fornitrice di servizi sociali,<br/> Viale Eleonora D'Arborea 12<br/> 00162 Roma<br/> <a href='http://www.prassiericerca.com' target='_blank'>Prassi e Ricerca</a>",
"icon": "img/orange-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "San Lorenzo", 
"latitude": 41.897379,
"longitude": 12.513272,
"content": "Penelope e altri servizi <a href='http://www.borghiartistici.com' target='_blank'>Borghi Artistici S.r.l.</a>",
"icon": "img/green-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "Giardinetti", 
"latitude": 41.898055,
"longitude": 12.515112,
"content": "ehi siamo in periferia <a href='http://www.eminem.com' target='_blank'>Eminem Official Web Site</a>",
"icon": "img/red-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "Montesacro", 
"latitude": 41.897825,
"longitude": 12.516436,
"content": "siamo a roma nord <a href='http://www.facebook.com' target='_blank'>Facebook Home Page</a>",
"icon": "img/yellow-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "Casa", 
"latitude": 41.899330,
"longitude": 12.516023,
"content": "siamo a casa mia che volete?ahah <a href='http://twitter.com' target='_blank'>Twitter Home Page</a>",
"icon": "img/prassi.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
},
{
"title": "C'era una volta il caffe", 
"latitude": 41.899998,
"longitude": 12.517145,
"content": "Bar Tabacchi, Caffe, Aperitivo, Cocktails, Lotto, Bollette",
"icon": "img/orange-dot.png",
"coords": "1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1",
"type": "poly"
}
]
```

> I truly hope my code is clear enough for you to find a way to solve the problem I am currently dealing with: once the markers are deleted I can't recreate them

Comment: How is the marker being "deleted?"

Comment: @APAD1 the markers are deleted using removeAddress function which is called inside the html page using onclick event that function contains a setallmap to null and an empty array which de facto removes the existing array. Have I been clear my friend?

Comment: It looks like the `removeAddress` function removes all markers, not just single ones, and clears the array of markers. Are you looking for a way to undo that action?

Comment: @APAD1 I am looking for a way to restore all of the deleted array I've removed earlier as a matter of fact I need to have the same markers back whenever I click on "cerca" button no matter the amount of time I click that button I need to create and destroy the same thing eldlessly

Comment: Within the `removeAddress` function, clone the array before resetting it. Something like `prevArr = arr.slice();`

Comment: @APAD1 please provide me an answer so that everything is clearer to me my friend

Comment: @APAD1 if I had two different json files which contain different coordinates could I create the former destroy it and then create the latter?

Answer (score 0):

This questions's a bit old, but I couldn't help notice... why delete the array at all? Just comment a line in `removeAddress()` method:

```
function removeAddress(){
    setAllMap(null);
    //arr = []; --let array stay in memory, so that setMap(map) can again display markers
}
```